# A question about holomorphic structure in Atiyah Bott's paper.

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

I am reading Atiyah & Bott's *The Yang-Mills equations over Riemann surfaces*. I meet a question about the holomorphic structure.

Let $E\to M$ be a complex vector bundle over a compact Riemann surface. There is a Hermitian metric on $E$.

Then 
\begin{equation}
 \mathscr A\cong\mathscr B
\end{equation}
for 
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  \mathscr A=&\{\text{all smooth hermitian connections}\}\\
  \mathscr B=&\{\text{all holomorphic structures on }E\}
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

The identification is described as: given a connection in $\mathscr A$
\begin{equation}
 d_A\colon\Omega^0(M;E)\to\Omega^1(M;E)
\end{equation}
then complexify it 
\begin{equation}
 d_A\colon\Omega^0_{\mathbb C}(M;E)\to\Omega^1_{\mathbb C}(M;E)
\end{equation}
and we have 
\begin{equation}
 \Omega^1_{\mathbb C}(M;E)=\Omega^{1,0}(M;E)\oplus\Omega^{0,1}(M;E)
\end{equation}

Then 
\begin{equation}
 d_A=d_A'\oplus d_A''
\end{equation}
for 
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  d_A'\colon & \Omega^0_{\mathbb C}(M;E)\to\Omega^{1,0}(M;E)\\
  d_A''\colon & \Omega^0_{\mathbb C}(M;E)\to\Omega^{0,1}(M;E)
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
and the operator $d_A''$ determines a holomorphic structure of $E$.

Questions:

1. The decomposition $\Omega^1_{\mathbb C}(M;E)=\Omega^{1,0}(M;E)\oplus\Omega^{0,1}(M;E)$ is due to a Hodge star operator. Is there a canonical Hodge star operator here? I know there is another decomposition using the canonical almost complex structure $J$, and I do not understand why not use this.
2. How to recover $d_A$ from $d_A''$? I guess here we need the Hermitian metric.

Thanks in advance.